# Making Data.Text.ICU.Convert.toUnicode report decoding failures

Tags: haskell, character-encoding, icu

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Text.IO
import Data.Text.ICU.Convert
import Prelude hiding (putStrLn)
main = do
    conv <- open "utf8" Nothing
    putStrLn $ toUnicode conv "h\xffzzah"
```

This program attempts to decode an invalid UTF-8 string; it prints "h�zzah", the converter having replaced the invalid byte with U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.  I would rather it threw an exception (say, `Data.Text.ICU.Error.ICUError`).  Is there a way to make it do so, or to otherwise report that the decoding didn't actually succeed?

Alternatively, is there a different way of doing character decoding in Haskell which reports errors of this type?

Comment: If the presence of a U+FFFD signals that the input was not a valid utf8 string, then define a function which performs the conversion, then throws an error if the result cotains that character.

Comment: @user2407038 but what if the FFFD was correctly encoded in the source document?

Comment: U+FFFD should only appear in documents following a conversion from a character which is "unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode". So either the error happened in your conversion or on some prior one. I have a hard time trying to think of a use case in which these two cases have to be handled differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beyond my comment above, here's a solution: count the number of occurences of U+FFFD in the input UTF-8 byte stream (this is a safe operation because UTF-8 is substring-safe -- see http://research.swtch.com/utf8), then count the occurences in the converted string. If they differ, you had an encoding error during YOUR conversion.